# Typescript conditional types in object destructuring

Tags: typescript

I want to call a function with an object as only argument. This object can be two different interfaces which collides (1+ properties have the same key but different possible values).

In my main function, I want to call `getFoo` if the type value in the object if **foo** and `getBar` if the type value in the object if **bar**.

```
interface Foo {
  title: string
  number: 1 | 2
}
interface FooWithType extends Foo {
  type: 'foo'
}

interface Bar {
  title: string
  number: 3 | 4
}
interface BarWithType extends Bar {
  type: 'bar'
}

function getFoo(params: Foo): void
function getBar(params: Bar): void

function main({ type, ...rest }: FooWithType | BarWithType) {
  return type === 'foo' ? getFoo(rest) : getBar(rest)
}
```

I have a TypeScript issue when I'm doing a conditional type on a destructured object where `Type '{ title: string; number: 3 | 4; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'` because my `rest` value is still an union type when I typecheck it:

```
var rest: {
    title: string;
    number: 1 | 2;
} | {
    title: string;
    number: 3 | 4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript do not understand the rest type because it's destructured so uncorrelated to the type value. There's two possible ways to fix it **without edit anything but the main function**.

The first is type assertion (**not recommended**):

```
function main({ type, ...rest }: FooWithType | BarWithType) {
  return type === 'foo' ? getFoo(rest as Foo) : getBar(rest as Bar)
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gUSAK4C2ARtNQIzIAPsgBMBAL4FQkWIhQZ0AdVIALACoBPAA4oIAD0ggAJjTSYcLYtqrIA5DEy2JBKeGjwkyAEJwoFwsSkFNR0DCDMAezcvMgAzELIACzO%20NLuct6%20ymDq1sj6hiaZfngBYNbUtly%20TviS%20ARGEAhkvigwbCAIJOggyIwQYAoAFFq%20cBw01AoAlNQAbujARo3NrVDtnd3Avf2DPlCj45PUB3PIi8su%20B1dPX0ccKDD2FY6ADTIAHQ-G3TI4mmmGyuR0CQOIM0Ohm-iIGzAbCgfXKYIAvOi7A50LZkAB%20PZDTDDP5gZBwUyzZDUAZgA7EiD-cnFGYSIA)

---

The second is to not destructure your object (**better way**):

```
function main(params: FooWithType | BarWithType) {
  return params.type === 'foo' ? getFoo(params) : getBar(params)
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gUSAK4C2ARtNQIzIAPsgBMBAL4FQkWIhQZ0AdVIALACoBPAA4oIAD0ggAJjTSYcLYtqrIA5DEy2JBKeGjwkyAEJwoFwsSkFNR0DCDMAezcvMgAzELIACzO%20NLuct6%20ymDq1sj6hiaZfngBYNbUtly%20TviS%20ARGEAhkvigwbCAIJOggyIwQYAoAFFq%20cBw01AoAlNQAbujARo3NrVDtnd3Avf2DPlCj45PUB3PIi8su%20B1dPX0ccKBHUBNTZkqqmjoJB9m5Ohm-iIGzAbCgfTGr0mADpyj8ALxIuwOdC2ZAAfj2Q0wLzeQOoAzABzxkxmEiAA)